# Angular : what does this @HostBinding mean here?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, and I am reading the ng-book and I found this code :

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  HostBinding
} from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product.model';

/**
 * @ProductRow: A component for the view of single Product
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'product-row',
  templateUrl: './product-row.component.html',
})
export class ProductRowComponent {
  @Input() product: Product;
  @HostBinding('attr.class') cssClass = 'item';
}
```

I don't understand why we use this line here

```
@HostBinding('attr.class') cssClass = 'item';
```

I searched some posts here and people say that it  "will bind the property to the host element, If a binding changes, HostBinding will update the host element".

But I checked the template file but I didn't find anything called "cssClass" or "item" inside :

```
<product-image [product]="product"></product-image>
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">{{ product.name }}</div>
  <div class="meta">
    <div class="product-sku">SKU #{{ product.sku }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <product-department [product]="product"></product-department>
  </div>
</div>
<price-display [price]="product.price"></price-display>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When angular **render** `product-row` it, you will see in DOM class in that element. In your case it will be `item`

So if you change `cssClass` to any value it will be automatically updated in DOM.

You can also do  data attributes `@HostBinding('attr.data-id')` or   `@HostBinding('style.background') backgroundColor = 'red';`

Its really handy as lets say you can add logic where you pass input parameter to your row, then based on that index lets say you assign your `cssClass` to be `item-odd` or `item-even` this way you can use some css to style your components

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, you mean it will add "item" in which template ? I checked the template which contains product-row in Chrome, but I found nothing (it's the same as in my source file) : <div class="ui items">
  <product-row
    *ngFor="let myProduct of productList"
    [product]="myProduct"
    (click)='clicked(myProduct)'
    [class.selected]="isSelected(myProduct)">
  </product-row>
</div>

Comment: @hawarden_ not template but in browsers DOM when it renders. So right click inspect element there you will see it

Comment: Ok indeed I see that, now I understand... just one question, what does attr.class mean ? does it refer to css ?

Comment: yes. it same if you do `product-row class="item"` but this way you control class name you can have some logic lets say if row index is 1 then do item-odd then item-even

Comment: @hawarden_ Ive updated answer. Hope it answers your questions

Comment: @hawarden_ all the best ;)